# GoogleMap dont let me insert marker in overlay zone

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have a script that works fine, the only problem is that googlemap is not letting me put the marker inside of one of the overlay zones, its "Zone 5",  green overlay color with dark red border. In the rest of the zones it works fine if you click inside it, the marker wont stay inside, but only in zone 5 is happening this situation.

Code for the click addEventListener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

  pos.lat = event.latLng.lat();
  pos.lng = event.latLng.lng();


  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
      geocoder.geocode({       
        latLng: latLng     
        }, 
        function(responses) 
        {     

           if (responses && responses.length > 0) 
           {        

            counter+=1; 
            if(counter == 1){
              //counter=(counter)?0:1; 
           // if(counter){
              origin_input.value= responses[0].formatted_address;
              origin_autocomplete.set('place',responses[0]);
              google.maps.event.trigger(origin_autocomplete,'place_changed');

            }else if(counter == 2){
                destination_input.value=responses[0].formatted_address;
              destination_autocomplete.set('place',responses[0]);
              google.maps.event.trigger(destination_autocomplete,'place_changed');

            }else {
              location.reload();
              /*destination_input.value=responses[0].formatted_address;
              destination_autocomplete.set('place',responses[0]);
              google.maps.event.trigger(destination_autocomplete,'place_changed');*/
            }

           } 
           else 
           {       
             alert('Not getting Any address for given latitude and longitude.');     
           }   
        });

});
```

And here is the polygon zone where i want the marker to stay after i  click on.

```
 var zone5 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone5_Coords,
    strokeColor: '#7f0502',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#02e500',//960502
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    clickable:false
  });
```

Link of script:

http://jsbin.com/qiwomutezi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site.

Comment: sorry @geocodezip i just updated my post.

Comment: My guess is the geocoder doesn't know of any addresses inside that polygon (the "airport").  Why are you using the geocoder?